# Integrate SharePoint Calendar in hybrid app

Tags: javascript, office-365, rest, sharepoint-calendar

I am trying to have a calendar feature in a hybrid mobile application. One company has a SharePoint site, whose calendar events i want to sync to the mobile app.

So far through REST i can see in a browser the xml with the calendar events of the site. Can i receive that XML with javascript in my mobile app context?

Is also a notification feasible, to notify when the calendar changed?

Answer (score 1):

Multiple points here:

1. REST should allow you to access Events data for sure. Not sure what
   you mean "mobile app context" - using simple HTTP calls
   (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj870858.aspx#BuildMobileAppsInSharePoint2013ForNonWindowsPhone_REST_EndpointsInSharePoint2013). Main issue here is getting your calls authentified, also have a look at this example http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj163303.aspx or http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj163201.aspx#BasicOps_SPJSOMOps
2. For notifications i would suggest you use a Remote event handler to
   send Push notification
   (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj163784.aspx#BKMK_ServerSideSolution)